# NextJs Link doesn't reload page but reloads components

Tags: dynamic, routes, next.js

I am new to nextjs and I am building my first website. My links are rendered with the following:

```
const menuList = menu.map(function(menuItem: any){
    return <Link href={`${menuItem.slug}`} key={menuItem.slug} as={`${menuItem.slug}`}>{menuItem.title}</Link>;
});
```

I have an index.tsx and [slug].tsx

When I click on a link it doesn't reload the entire page but the blue menu and image flashe white. I was expecting just the 'I made it to about us' content to change and the image and menu would not appear to change. Am I missing something or is this expected? If I hit the back button I get the results I expect. I read to use 'as' on Link but that doesn't seem to help. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Do you experience the same when running the production build with `next build && next start`? Also, using `as` in this case is not needed since it's the same value as `href`.

Comment: Yes, also when I run `next build && next export` and push the static files it does the same thing.